# make shutdown / reboot warn on a shared server in case of user sessions or high load

Tags: linux, users, root, maintenance, warning

Is there an easy way to warn an admin on shutdown, reboot, poweroff, halt, ... about:

- ongoing computations (high load, high disk io)
- open bash / zsh / ... terminal sessions
- other logged in users
- screen / tmux sessions

I'm looking for a solution that will support admins to not accidentally bin a lot of work.

Setting: Co-operative environment (15 users, all know each other). We use a shared server with multiple users and admins. Many users do long calculations in `screen` / `tmux` sessions. Even though admins should know better, it happens from time to time that they reboot the machine and accidentally disturb ongoing work of logged in users.

Comment: Why it is required to reboot server from time to time? Isn't it stable enough? You may need to reboot a server for example when applying a kernel patch. Other software updates and configuration should not mandate server reboot!

Comment: we reboot them just for fun ;)... yes, kernel updates, even though one could in theory do them without along the lines of liveupdate, ksplice, kpatch... (offtopic here though)

Comment: This does not require a technological solution. I think it's a people issue. Communicate downtime windows and be more judicious about your reboot schedule.

Comment: i agree... sadly there were constellations where this communication failed :(. Hence, i'm asking for a tech support solution, that will actually make an admin very aware of what he's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a debian package called `molly-guard`. It asks you to type in the hostname so you don't accidentally shutdown the wrong machine. By default this is only switched on for SSH connections, but you can set `ALWAYS_QUERY_HOSTNAME=true` in `/etc/molly-guard/rc` so it always asks.

Also, to make the admin aware of what's going on, we added the following `/etc/molly-guard/run.d/20-own-warning` file:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo
echo "current logins: w:"
w
echo
echo "current logins: who:"
who
echo
echo "current open terminals: ps aux | grep -E '(bash)|(zsh)'"
ps aux | grep -E '(bash)|(zsh)'
echo
echo
echo "Before shutdown/reboot, please contact all of the above users!!!"
echo

exit 0
```

Comment: `molly-guard` runs a series of scripts before prompting for the hostname so it would seem like you could add one to check for the things he mentioned without too much work.

Comment: edited the answer to include our example, thanks for the pointer